# Prevent other APKs from accessing my resources?

Tags: android

In Android it is possible to access and use another APK's resources through [getResourcesForApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29). Is it possible to prevent other APKs from using this method to access my app's resources?